# "Battle.net is unable to identify your application version" in Wine (Linux)

Tags: diablo-ii, linux, wine

In downgrading my patched 1.14 install to the mod-compatible 1.13 version, I received the following error: "Battle.net is unable to identify your application version"

Most sites say that this indicates a permissions issue and that **the user should run the exe in Windows XP Compatibility Mode** (right-click, properties, Compatibility). But I was working in `wine`, which automatically runs programs as admin (not the same as running under root, which is verboten) so it wasn't a permission issue. What is causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above, the [most common fix](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/unable-to-identify-application-version) for this error is to right-click the exe and "Run as administrator".

But that doesn't fix it or if you're running `wine`, I was able to narrow the issue to the registry (`wine regedit`). Removing the two Diablo II folders (in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` and `HKEY_USERS`) did not appear to work, so I blew both the "Software" folders (two levels up) and restored the Software folder from another wineprefix (instance of `wine`). Error's gone. It is likely that a fresh install would also work in this case--the main issue appeared to be a conflict between former Battle.net registry files and the patched exe.

[image: registry]

Answer (score 0):

I have found that when updating your Diablo II executable to the latest available version you will want to change directories to the program folder that you have Diablo II installed in.  For example, if you installed it to /home/username/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Diablo II/ then you would run the following:

```
cd /home/caseyb/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Diablo II
wine ./Game.exe
```

As a final note, this process is only for when you have to update your Diablo 2 install.  You can run the game as normal once it is up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

IF you previously added a 3rd party mod, check the registry key here: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Battle.net/Configuration`. Delete the key `Diablo II Battle.net gateways`. Then start D2 and select multiplayer... it will rebuild the key.

I'm running windows 7 and a clean D2 install did not work, the above mentioned did.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a post on a almost 5 year old thread, but I had this same problem and the above fix's did not work for me. However with a bit of work I was able to figure out how to solve it and thought I would share it so that other people can play on Battle.net with their friends (or solo).
I made a quick 2 minute youtube video to show how it is done.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/319755)